# IDA 6.9 IDC AddStrucMember

Tags: ida

In IDA if I change the type of a struct member (using D hotkey) and dump to idc database in that IDC file it correctly produces an AddStrucMember command for that member.

The problem is that if I change that member again (still with D) and then load the previously produced IDC script it fails to return said member to its original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test**

Testing with a dummy struct :

```
00000000 FooTest         struc ; (sizeof=0x8, mappedto_126)
00000000 f0              dd ?
00000004 f2              dd ?
00000008 FooTest         ends
```

Export it to IDC (`File > Produce File > Dump typeinfo to IDC file...`)

Change to the following:

```
00000000 FooTest         struc ; (sizeof=0x8, mappedto_126)
00000000 f0              dw ?
00000002 f1              dw ?
00000004 f2              dd ?
00000008 FooTest         ends
```

Reloading the idc file doesn't change anything...

**Check**

Checking with python:

```
Python>id = GetStrucIdByName("FooTest");
Python>id
18374686479671636282
Python>mid = AddStrucMember(id,"f0",    0,  0x20000400, -1, 4)
Python>mid
-2
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/398.shtml), `-2` is an error :

> STRUC_ERROR_MEMBER_OFFSET  (-2) // already has member at this offset

**Possible solution**

So, the best option is to delete the existing struct, you can use the `del` key on the struct window or python / idc with [`DelStruc`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/394.shtml):

```
Python>id = GetStrucIdByName("FooTest")
Python>id
18374686479671636398
Python>r = DelStruc(id)
Python>r
True
```

And then reload the (backup) idc file.

The struct is back, as saved (notice the `mappedto_xxx` has changed):

```
00000000 FooTest         struc ; (sizeof=0x8, mappedto_127)
00000000 f0              dd ?
00000004 f2              dd ?
00000008 FooTest         ends
```